# how to selected vocabulary in scikit CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, term-document-matrix

I have used scikit [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to convert collection of documents into matrix of token counts. I have also used its max_features which considers the top max_features ordered by term frequency across the corpus.

Now I want to analyse my selected corpus, especially I want to know frequency of tokens in selected vocabulary. But I am unable to find an easy way to do it. So kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @bernard post, I am able to completely get the result, which is as follows:

```
vec = CountVectorizer()
doc_term_matrix = vec.fit_transform(['toto titi', 'toto toto', 'titi tata'])
doc_term_matrix = doc_term_matrix.toarray()
term_freq_matrix = doc_term_matrix.sum(0)
min_freq = np.amin(term_freq_matrix)
indices_name_mapping = vec.get_feature_names()
feature_names = [indices_name_mapping[i] for i, x in enumerate(term_freq_matrix) if x == min_freq]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fit_transform()` a sparse matrix will be returned.

To display it you simply have to call the toarray() method.

```
vec = CountVectorizer()
spars_mat = vec.fit_transform(['toto titi', 'toto toto', 'titi tata'])

#you can observer the matrix in the interpretor by doing
spars_mat.toarray()
```